# ale linter + eslint: Jump to next error

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-ale

[image]

I use `eslint` with [`ale`](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) to lint my Javascript code. After editing a code block, I often have a few errors to fix. Fixing is done by navigating to the next erroneous line, reading the problem from the ruler and fixing.

If I could skip the navigation phase and use a specific key binding to navigate to the location of the next error - its line, and hopefully its column - it would be great.

**Is there a way to use key binding to navigate to the next lint/ale error?**

Answer (score 38):

ALE has many commands that can navigate linting errors, and `:ALENext` works great for this operation. By default, ALE maps no bindings, I assume to allow for non-clashing customization.

In your `~/.vimrc` (or `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` for NeoVim), I use:

```
nmap <silent> <leader>aj :ALENext<cr>
nmap <silent> <leader>ak :ALEPrevious<cr>
```

Leader is <kbd>\</kbd> by default

Comment: Maybe worth adding that if you want to jump specifically to errors or warnings, that (verbatim from the docs):  "`-error`, `-warning` and `-info` enable jumping to errors, warnings or infos respectively, ignoring anything else. They are mutually exclusive and if several are provided the priority is the following: error > warning > info."

Answer (score 15):

You can easily move between errors by adding some key bindings to ale's `<Plug>` mappings (see `:h <Plug>`).

In this [example](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#5xi-how-can-i-navigate-between-errors-quickly) use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to go to next error and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to go to the previous error.

```
nmap <silent> <C-k> <Plug>(ale_previous_wrap)
nmap <silent> <C-j> <Plug>(ale_next_wrap)
```

Comment: This assumes that you have Plug rather than Vundle or Pathogen installed.

Comment: This appears to come direct from the ALE repo README: https://github.com/w0rp/ale#5ix-how-can-i-navigate-between-errors-quickly